Why do you add wire in polygon pour?
The PCB design is from STM32H7 Nucleo-144 boards


The 3V3_VDD already has polygon pour plane. Why do they still add this wire?

It depends on the workflow of the PCB designer.
Personally, I dislike working with polygons on screen.
I disable them or only add them at the end of my routing.
In the meantime I want to make sure that some critical nets, that will be connected by a polygon pour eventually, are connected in a good way.
The design rule check tool checks that a net is connected, but not that the path used to do that connection is good. The signal may be running all around your board, changing planes and using 10 vias, the design rule check tool will be happy with that. I may not be happy with that...
By routing that net, I ensure that it has at least a good path available.
Another reason is related to the way polygon pours are connected to pads. If you want a beefy connection between the polygon and a pad and not the small thermal reliefs, you have basically two options :

You change the rule that defines the connection between that specific polygon and the pad. And during a repour it will be fine. It's the proper way but it's slow, and peoples are lazy....

or

You add manually a large trace from the pad to the polygon and that's it. Quick and dirty.

It could also means that the design was not supposed to use polygons initially. But at the end, the designer thought that a polygon would be better here, and he simple added it on top of the previous routing.


Why do you add wire in polygon pour?

The short answer is that the designer routed 3V3_VDD as a track/trace then decided to beef up the trace with a copper pour. He/she could have subsequently removed the trace but, it isn't necessary or vital to do so.
